# How to apply conditional formatting formula to large range faster

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I created a conditional formatting formula

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$" & lastRow & "=$A2)*($CT$2:$CT$" & lastRow & "=$CT2)*($CU$2:$CU$" & lastRow & "=$CU2)*($CV$2:$CV$" & lastRow & "=$CV2)*($CW$2:$CW$" & lastRow & "=$CW2))>1,$CT2 <> """")"
```

To find & highlight duplicate upcharges based on multiple criteria:
Product's XID (Column A), Upcharge Criteria 1 (Column CT), Upcharge Criteria 2 (Column CU), Upcharge Type (Column CV), and Upcharge Level (Column CW). The formula works like a charm highlighting upcharges that are duplicates; however, much of the time I have to apply it to a large number of rows (upwards of 15000) and it takes 10+ minutes to apply the conditional format formula. I was curious if there is a quicker way of applying this formula to that many cells. My entire code for reference is

```
'File Complete, highlights duplicate upcharges for products and skips over blank upcharge rows
Sub dupUpchargeCheck()

Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "CS").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("CS2:CS" & lastRow).Select
With ActiveSheet.Range("CS2:CS" & lastRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$" & lastRow & "=$A2)*($CT$2:$CT$" & lastRow & "=$CT2)*($CU$2:$CU$" & lastRow & "=$CU2)*($CV$2:$CV$" & lastRow & "=$CV2)*($CW$2:$CW$" & lastRow & "=$CW2))>1,$CT2 <> """")"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End With

End Sub
```

Any advice is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

After toying around a bit, I've realized my problem isn't with the application of the conditional formatting formula to the range of cells, but actually when I click the drop down to filter on the color (after the code is ran and the conditional formatting is applied) it takes forever for the filter dropdown box to appear (I assume because all of the formulas calculating at that time?). Any idea how I can get around that issue? I've tried one of @Nate suggestions of
`calcState = Application.Calculation`, placing it right before the line where I filtered (via vba) in hopes that it would stop the calculations from running as the system attempted to show the filter box, but it still takes forever. With the addition `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` the processing time takes slightly less time (timed around 551 seconds for 15000 rows). I'm afraid that might be the best I'll be able to get it unless someone else has any suggestions?

Comment: If you're on Excel 2007 or higher, use `COUNTIFS` instead of `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of finding the duplicates and marking them with a color? Do you wish to delete them or store them elsewhere or what? It might actually be solved a lot more elegantly.

Comment: No, the solution is much more complicated. Basically, something has to be changed on one of each pair of duplicates (be it changing the Upcharge type or Upcharge level, etc) so they aren't exactly the same. All upcharges must stay.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off some Excel features before your code then turning them back on when it is done.

```
' turn off unnecessary excel features, put before your code
screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating
statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar
calcState = Application.Calculation
eventsState = Application.EnableEvents
displayPageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

Then

```
' Turn features back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState
```

Comment: This will not speed up the actual calculation; you turn it to xlCalculationManual and set it back. Excel will only calculate once this happens and then there's still a 10 min wait. It is true that in general this will speed up macro execution when referencing cells etc.

Comment: This is useful information for me still as I can use it speed up my overall macro (a much bigger project), so thank you. I've realized where my issue is and it's not within the application process of the formula, but when trying to filter that column anytime after the formulas have been applied. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I just realized I may have not implemented the 'calcstate = Application.Calculation' code correctly since I just added that line of code and left out what looks like the second part 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual'. Even though @RikSportel has a point when talking about turning it off before applying the conditional formatting formula to the range, but would this actually help in my case where it would help the filter go quicker AFTER the conditional formatting formatting has been applied to the range?

Answer (score 0):

This didn't help me before, but I hope it help you as [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840811.aspx) said :

> This is particularly useful when condition is applied over a large range as performance can be slow in these cases.

```
ActiveSheet.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = False

'.....

ActiveSheet.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True
```

Maybe this not work on MAC.
[ActiveSheet.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation Not Supported in VBA for Excel 2011 on the Mac](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/activesheetenableformatconditionscalculation-not/e303f855-4e73-4d27-81c7-95df7131cc2b?db=5&auth=1)