# Finding (NOT deleting) duplicate values/"rows" in multi-dimensional array using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

<sup>Building off of one of my past [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183844/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-formula-to-large-range-faster)</sup>
**What I'm looking to accomplish:**

I'm looking to find and highlight duplicate Upcharges using VBA code based on multiple criteria:

1. Product's XID (Column A)
2. Upcharge Criteria 1 (Column CT)
3. Upcharge Criteria 2 (Column CU)
4. Upcharge Type (Column CV) and
5. Upcharge Level (Column CW)

If there is more than one instance/row in a spreadsheet that share/match ALL of these criteria then that means the Upcharge is a duplicate. As seen in my previous post linked above:

**What I've tried:**

1. Created a general formula (see below) that is inserted into a Helper column and copied all the way down the spreadsheet which points out which Upcharges are duplicate. This method was too resource heavy and took too long (8-10 minutes for all the formulas to calculate, but doesn't lag when filtering). Then I tried
2. Evolved the general formula into a Conditional Formatting Formula and applied it to the Upcharge Name column via VBA code.(Takes same amount of time AND lags when filtering)
3. I've also looked into possibly using a `scripting.dictionary`, but I'm not sure how (or if) that would work with a multi-dimensional array.

Now I've finally found the method I think will be much faster,

**The faster method I'm looking to use:**
Dumping the aforementioned columns into a multi-dimensional array, finding the duplicate "rows" in the array, then highlighting the corresponding spreadsheet rows.

**My attempt at the faster method:**
Here's how I populate the multi-dimensional array

```
Sub populateArray()
    Dim arrXID() As Variant, arrUpchargeOne() As Variant, arrUpchargeTwo() As Variant, arrUpchargeType() As Variant, arrUpchargeLevel() As Variant
    Dim arrAllData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lrow As Long
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    arrXID = Range("A2:A" & lrow) 'amend column number
    arrUpchargeOne = Range("CT2:CT" & lrow)
    arrUpchargeTwo = Range("CU2:CU" & lrow)
    arrUpchargeType = Range("CV2:CV" & lrow)
    arrUpchargeLevel = Range("CW2:CW" & lrow)

    ReDim arrAllData(1 To UBound(arrXID, 1), 4) As Variant
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrXID, 1)
            arrAllData(i, 0) = arrXID(i, 1)
            arrAllData(i, 1) = arrUpchargeOne(i, 1)
            arrAllData(i, 2) = arrUpchargeTwo(i, 1)
            arrAllData(i, 3) = arrUpchargeType(i, 1)
            arrAllData(i, 4) = arrUpchargeLevel(i, 1)
        Next i
End Sub
```

I can get the columns into the array, but I get stuck from there. I'm not sure how to go about checking for the duplicate "rows" in the array.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a way I can apply my formula (see below) from my first attempt in my previous post and apply it inside the array?:
2. Or, even better, is there a faster way I can find the duplicate "rows" inside the array?
3. Then how could I go about highlighting the Upcharge Name (CS) cell in the spreadsheet rows that correspond with the "rows" in the array that were flagged as duplicates?

<sub>Formula from my previous post for reference:</sub>

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$" & lastRow & "=$A2)*($CT$2:$CT$" & lastRow & "=$CT2)*($CU$2:$CU$" & lastRow & "=$CU2)*($CV$2:$CV$" & lastRow & "=$CV2)*($CW$2:$CW$" & lastRow & "=$CW2))>1,$CT2 <> """")"
Returns TRUE if Upcharge is a duplicate
```